# capture UIImage from CMSampleBuffer (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

I try to capture an UIImage from a CMSampleBuffer to read the text. But I always get the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I was looking around and tried a lot of versions. But I always get the same error.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
}
```

kindly Regards!

Comment: You don't say which unwrap is throwing the error. `image` or `uiImage`?

Comment: You are using the wrong uiimage initializer. You need to use ciimage instead of cgimage

Answer (score 1):

[`CIImage.cgImage`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreimage/ciimage/1687603-cgimage) applies only when the `CIImage` was created from a `CGImage`. When you create a `CIImage` from a pixel buffer, it has no underlying `CGImage` so that property is nil.

You can [initialize a `UIImage` direct from a `CIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624114-init), but how that works for you will depend on where/how you render that image. (For example rendering CI-backed `UIImage`s in, say, `UIImageView` gives poor performance in iOS 9 and older if you're doing it in realtime.)

Answer (score -2):

To get the UIImage via CIImage you should use **CIContext.** 
Below is Obj-C code:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
```

And then:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:yourCIImage fromRect:[yourCIImage extent] ];
UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

This approach claims it only uses GPU and thus is fast. 
But there are other methods to obtain UIImage from the **CVPixelBuffer**, like using **CGContextRef**.